# flatten_images with transparent background using RMagick gem

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, transparency

Seems like I'd be able to find this, but can't turn up anything. Have a short script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'

img = Magick::ImageList.new("public/images/dev_banner_background.png")
gc = Magick::Draw.new

img.annotate(gc, 0,0,15,130, "| #{ENV['SERVER_TYPE']} Server |") do
  self.pointsize = 13
  self.rotation = -45
  self.kerning = 1
  self.stroke = "#ffffff"
  self.fill = "#ffffff"
end

picture = img.flatten_images

picture.write("public/images/dev_banner.png")
```

dev_banner_background.png is a small banner on a transparent background similar to Github's "Fork me on Github" banner.

Works well to overlay this text on the banner (want to overlay on dev/staging servers). But the resulting images has a white background. Assuming it's in the flatten_images call, but can't figure out how to make it flatten with transparency. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
  img = Magick::ImageList.new("public/images/dev_banner_background.png")
  img.background_color = "none"
  gc = Magick::Draw.new
```

I was trying to set background color in `flatten_images`, and in the `annotate` method. I didn't realize that `ImageList` had a `background_color` attribute directly, since I didn't see it in the list of [instance methods and attributes](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html). Maybe I just missed it.

Comment: Looks like this method has gone away as it doesn't work for me.